# Brick FTP upload file using brick_ftp gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ftp, rubygems

I have trouble with uploading file using brick_ftp gem
I am using dropzone.js for front end.
This is my source code for uploading

```
BrickFTP::API::FileOperation::Upload.create(:path =>
params[:file].original_filename, :source => params[:file])
```

`Dropzone.js` is working well.
It is uploading `0 kb` of same name file to brick ftp.
I think the main problem is with source parameter.

Please help me if anyone knows about it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem myself like this.

`BrickFTP::API::FileOperation::Upload.create(:path =>
params[:file].original_filename, :source => params[:file].tempfile.to_io)`

It is working very well.